# Include specific date in title of a ggplot2-plot

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2

is it possible to include a specific date (i.e. yesterday's date) in a ggplot2-graph-title oder -subtitle (directly as Sys.Date or stored in an object, i.e. `date_yesterday <- as.Date(paste0(format(as.Date(Sys.Date()), "%Y-%m-%d")))-1`? I haven't found any answer to far.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You can just do `ggtitle(paste('Plot Yesterday', Sys.Date()-1, sep = " ")) `

Comment: Thank your for your hints and the link. Works perfectly well.